# Why would UIPinchGestureRecognizer not be called, while scrollViewDidEndZooming is?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gesture

I have a UIViewController, which uses a UIScrollView and within that Scrollview it has a UIImageView.

I want to recognize a pinch and zoom accordingly. I don't need to scale, i just need to show a different image.

It pretty much looks like this question: [UIView UIPinchGestureRecognizer problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735440/uiview-uipinchgesturerecognizer-problem)

I have tried several things:

- set contentMode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`
- set `multipleTouchEnabled = YES`
- set `userInteractionEnabled = YES`

And yet, it still not always catches the pinching event.

Here is how I assign the gesture to the view, pretty straightforward:

```
   UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(zoomPinch:)];
    [MediaScroller addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
    [pinchRecognizer release];
```

Also, I do notice that the `scrollViewDidEndZooming` is called of my delegate, but the scale variable is always 1.0. How can that be?

The `scrollViewDidEndZooming` is always called, while the pinch method (zoomPinch) is not always called. Any reasons why that would happen? And how can I fix it? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to implement this in your `recognizer delegate`:

```
pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

then, on self class:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
     return YES;
}
```

As the class already recognizes pinch (for zoom), maybe you need to enable to have more than one handler for pinch.

Comment: I'm willing to try anything to fix this. However, when I set delegate to self, it won't compile. As 'self' is a:

`@interface image_zoomController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not just as good in ObjectiveC, i have added UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to the Protocols, and now it compiles. Lets see if it works! :)